# DLL not being recognized

Tags: c#

I am trying to create and use a dll file for my school project. I followed the steps in http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/54433-creating-a-dll-to-store-common-methods-in-c%23/
but my project cant find the dll. Here is my code:

```
namespace DBSql
{
    class DBSql
    {
       //some static methods
     }
}
```

I then build the class library and in the release folder, there is a DbSql.dll file. I add it as reference to my wndows project. But when I try to type DBSql, the project does not even find it. Am I missing a step?

Comment: Could you clarify: Your project can't find the dll, or can't find the class?

Comment: u using the `using` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 Things to try:

1) Make your class public

```
namespace DBSql
{
    public class DBSql
    {
       //some static methods
     }
}
```

2) When you are trying to reference the class, add a using statement at the top of your file:

```
using DBSql;
```

**But**, I think you may have an issue with conflicting Namespace and Class. So maybe change one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you type `DBSql` that calls the namespace. You have to type another `DBSql` so that it is `DBSql.DBSql.SomeStaticFunction()` because your namespace's name is the same with your class. Also make your class public.